# A bit of help making an ordinal clock conversion

Tags: c, visual-studio

Currently, I have an assignment to make a piece of code that asks for the user's input before converting it to an ordinal clock, as well as an exception in the case of a leap year. The only issue is that I don't know what I'm doing in the case of putting arrays in functions.

```
/*The purpose of this program is to make the user enter a date and return the info as ordinal*/


#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAXDAYSINMONTH 12 /*Define maximums for dates*/
#define MAXDAYS 365

int main()
{
    void findDate(int[], int *, int *); /*Prototype*/
int daysInMonth[MAXDAYSINMONTH]; /*Variables for function*/

int days, months, year, dayTest; /*Variables for user*/

printf("This Program will ask you for the date\n");
printf("Please enter the Day: "); /*Get User input*/
scanf("%d", &days);
printf("\nPlease enter the Month: ");
scanf("%d", &months);
printf("\nPlease enter the Year: ");
scanf("%d", &year);

findDate(days, months, &dayTest);/*call the function*/


/**
* Input:   Actual Date
* Process: Conversion
* Output:  Ordinal Date
*/

printf("The ordinal date for the date entered is: ", dayTest);/*Get Output*/
if (year / 4 == 0) { /*Look for Leap Year*/
    if (dayTest > 59) {
        dayTest = dayTest + 1;
    }
    printf("This date is a leap year");
}
else
    printf("This date is not a leap year");

return 0;
}
/*Convert Regular Date to Ordinal*/
void findDate(int days, int months, int* dayTest, int daysInMonths[]) {
    int daysInMonth[MAXDAYSINMONTH], dayTest; /*Variables for function*/
    daysInMonth[0] = 31;
    daysInMonth[1] = 28;
    daysInMonth[2] = 31;
    daysInMonth[3] = 30;
    daysInMonth[4] = 31;
    daysInMonth[5] = 30;
    daysInMonth[6] = 31;
    daysInMonth[7] = 31;
    daysInMonth[8] = 30;
    daysInMonth[9] = 31;
    daysInMonth[10] = 30;
    daysInMonth[11] = 31;
    if (months > 31) {
        *dayTestaddr = days + daysInMonth;
    }
}
```

New code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAXDAYSINMONTH 12 /*Define maximums for dates*/
#define MAXDAYS 365

void findDate(int days, int months, int* dayTest, int daysInMonths[]); /*Prototype*/

int main()
{

    int daysInMonth[MAXDAYSINMONTH]; /*Variables for function*/

    int days, months, year, dayTest; /*Variables for user*/

    printf("This Program will ask you for the date\n");
    printf("Please enter the Day: "); /*Get User input*/
    scanf("%d", &days);
    printf("\nPlease enter the Month: ");
    scanf("%d", &months);
    months = months - 1;
    printf("\nPlease enter the Year: ");
    scanf("%d", &year);

    findDate(days, months, &dayTest, daysInMonth); /*call the function*/


    /**
    * Input:   Actual Date
    * Process: Conversion
    * Output:  Ordinal Date
    */

    printf("The ordinal date for the date entered is: %d%d", year, dayTest);/*Get Output*/

    if (year % 4 == 0) { /*Look for Leap Year*/
        if (dayTest > 59) {
            dayTest = dayTest + 1;
        }
        printf("\nThis date is a leap year");
    }
    else
        printf("\nThis date is not a leap year");
    
    return 0;
}
/*Convert Regular Date to Ordinal*/
void findDate(int days, int months, int* dayTest, int daysInMonths[]) {
    daysInMonths[0] = 31;
    daysInMonths[1] = 28;
    daysInMonths[2] = 31;
    daysInMonths[3] = 30;
    daysInMonths[4] = 31;
    daysInMonths[5] = 30;
    daysInMonths[6] = 31;
    daysInMonths[7] = 31;
    daysInMonths[8] = 30;
    daysInMonths[9] = 31;
    daysInMonths[10] = 30;
    daysInMonths[11] = 31;
    if (months > 11 || months < 0)
    {
        // Illegal call
        printf("Your month is over 12 or under 0, try again\n");
    }
    if (months == 0) {
        *dayTest = days;
    }
    else 
        *dayTest = days + (daysInMonths[months] - daysInMonths[1]);
}
```

I'm just saving this so my progress can be more apparent, I do think I have a general handle, but I still need to keep going forward in regards to making an ordinal date in the format of YYYY-DDD. Help would be appreciated, and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The declarations of `findDate` are inconsistent and the prototype should be placed before `main`.

Your prototype:

```
void findDate(int[], int *, int *); /*Prototype*/
```

Your call:

```
findDate(days, months, &dayTest);
          ^       ^
          |       Not an int*
          Not an array
```

Your definition:

```
void findDate(int days, int months, int* dayTest, int daysInMonths[])
```

Here you have 4 parameters but previously you only had 3. Also the individual parameter doesn't match previously definitions.

You need to fix this inconsistency.

Before `main` put:

```
void findDate(int days, int months, int* dayTest, int daysInMonths[]);
```

In `main` call it like:

```
findDate(days, months, &dayTest, daysInMonth);
```

And don't redefine variables like `daysInMonth` and `dayTest` in the function body. Simply do:

```
void findDate(int days, int months, int* dayTest, int daysInMonths[]) {
    daysInMonth[0] = 31;
    daysInMonth[1] = 28;
    daysInMonth[2] = 31;
    daysInMonth[3] = 30;
    daysInMonth[4] = 31;
    daysInMonth[5] = 30;
    daysInMonth[6] = 31;
    daysInMonth[7] = 31;
    daysInMonth[8] = 30;
    daysInMonth[9] = 31;
    daysInMonth[10] = 30;
    daysInMonth[11] = 31;
    if (months >= 12 || months < 0) 
    {
        // Illegal call
        .. error handling ..
    }
    *dayTest = days + daysInMonth[months];
}
```

That said, why have the `daysInMonths` array as a variable that you fill every time you call the function? It's a waste of CPU cycles. Instead make it a global constant.

So **before** `main` do:

```
const int daysInMonth[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, ....};
```

then you don't need to pass the array at all and your function get much simpler:

```
void findDate(int days, int months, int* dayTest) {
    if (months >= 12 || months < 0) 
    {
        // Illegal call
        .. error handling ..
    }
    *dayTest = days + daysInMonth[months];
}
```

or simplify further by using a return value instead of a pointer:

```
int findDate(int days, int months) {
    assert(months >= 0 && months < 12); 
    return days + daysInMonth[months];
}
```

and call it like:

```
dayTest = findDate(days, months);
```

Much simpler... no pointers, no arrays to be passed to the function.

Final note... Array index starts from zero but your user will probably input `1` for january. So you have an inconsistency that must be handled.

Comment: Okay, so far it's going well, no major errors, but I would like to have it come out in YYYY-DDD format. Also, I want the array to add the days of the previous month to the function, but I don't want to go full yandev and post if else statements for every month, so if you could, can you please look it over? It should be under "New Code" in this post.